# Is it possible to bind mesh to armature using its current pose?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, cloth-simulation

I am looking for solution where i can import premade clothes which might be in

- t-pose, A-pose
- slightly out of the bone's default state
- or use cloth sim to get a good resting pose with wrinkles and cloth not going inside the body

and get them to follow my main rig without using proportional editing.

I need to export the models with the rig as glb with default pose but would like to use the resting pose cloth sim as it looks the most normal.

python suggestions welcome . Maybe something like :

- make the resting pose as default pose
- bind mesh rig
- revert back to original default pose
  [image]

[image] dummy test file used in above screenshot

Comment: Rest pose is the default pose, and is not referring to the character relaxing. Aside, this is doable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer:

1. Save the default pose as a keyframe
2. Go to resting pose ,press ctrl +A to set this pose as new default
3. Bind mesh  to this pose
4. Go to the saved keyframe pose and set this to default to revert back to the original A pose or T pose

Answer (score 1):

For fitting clothes, there are a number of options, but I think the best (some balance of easy and works well) is to use a surface deform modifier.

I'm going to assume you have a body mesh for that armature.  Pose the armature to fit the piece of clothing, then give the clothing a surface deform modifier targeting the body mesh and bind.  You can now reset your armature to its rest position if desired.

If the goal is rendering in Blender, the surface deform is fine-- there's no need to go further.  However, since your goal is export, you can apply the surface deform modifier after resetting the pose, and then weight (probably from a data transfer from your body.)

This can sometimes create problems near sharp bends-- at armpits in an A pose, at the groin.  This can be worked around by surface deforming different parts of the clothing from different subsections of the body.  Vertex groups are useful for this.